# How to sort pages alphabetically

Tags: powershell, sorting, onenote

I am trying to write a simple PowerShell that reads the XML for a OneNote Notebook and sort the tabs/pages alphabetically. I have been able to sort them in the XML, but when I run UpdateHierarchy, the command runs, but the file is not updated in the end. What am I missing?

Below is a snippet of a trial just to swap two pages around. Here is the output from the script before and after the swap below...

```
== BEFORE ==
Notebook: Test Notebook
# Section A
### My Page
### Another Page
### Third Page in Section A
### B Page
### 123 Page
# Section B
### This has no title
### Untitled page

== AFTER ==
Notebook: Test Notebook
# Section A
### My Page
### Another Page
### Third Page in Section A
### B Page
### 123 Page
# Section B
### Untitled page
### This has no title

#Trial Code
$Page0 = $NoteBook.Section[1].Page[0]
$Page1 = $NoteBook.Section[1].Page[1]
$NoteBook.Section[1].InsertAfter($Page0,$Page1)
([XML]$Hierarchy).Notebooks.Notebook[$NoteBookIndex].InnerXml = $NoteBook.InnerXml
$OneNote.UpdateHierarchy($Hierarchy)
```

However, when I open the Notebook in the OneNote, it is still in the same order as it was before.